# ImageDataGenerator - trained with model.fit instead of model.fit_generator

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am a beginner in using the ImageDataGenerator from Keras and I accidentally used model.fit instead of model.fit_generator.

```
train_gen = gen_Image_data()
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_samples = train_gen.flow(X,y, batch_size=64)
test_samples = test_gen.flow(X_val, y_val, batch_size=64)
history = model.fit(train_samples, steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(len(X)/64),
                  validation_data=(test_samples),
                  validation_steps=np.ceil(len(X_val)/64),
                  epochs=300, verbose=1, callbacks=[es])
```

Is that a glaring mistake, do I have to re-train everything with fit_generator?

Thanks for every help

**Update** I have forgotten the code for `gen_Image_data()`

```
def gen_Image_data():
   gen = ImageDataGenerator(
         width_shift_range=0.1,
         horizontal_flip=True)
   return gen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have bother re-training the model, because `model.fit` method supports generators as well and also `model.fit_generator` is subsumed by `model.fit` method!

Comment: But is the data really augmented (please see Update above)?

Comment: Please also look at  
 point 2 in   
   https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/#attachment_9327